# reactJS with jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm pretty new to ReactJS and a bit confused on how to use it. I understand the basics but when I want to build more complex things, I tend to start thinking in jQuery or JavaScript. For instance if I want to build a web app that print letters from a string on page load, I know how to do it in jQuery but I have no idea how to create it with React. And the tutorials covers only the basics. So my question is, how can I learn to use React in more complex ways? Is it possible to use jQuery or JS in React?

Comment: I would like to point out, technically you're already using js when you're doing react (hence the js), react is supposed to help with the view part of an MVC framework. but what do you mean "more complex ways"

Comment: @Daemedeor I understand that React technically is JS. What confuses me is what I can and can't use. Can I use, for example, alert, append, for, if, in the same way in React as I do in Vanilla JS or jQuery? I hope you understand my question, it's a bit hard to explain and it may sound as a strange question.

Comment: Why not watch some tutorials and follow more instructional guides? There are hundreds of great resources available. You're also confusing JavaScript the programming language with browser features. For example, `append` is not Javascript. It's part of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Basic js is easy obviously, but plugin use is documented here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I'll continue to study it to understand more.